# .htaccess AuthType not what I expected

Tags: php, .htaccess, shibboleth

I'm working on a new project at work in PhP, and have come across something I'm unfamiliar with/can't find any help with.

In the .htaccess file for the directory I see

```
AuthType UWNetID
require valid-user
```

I have only ever seen basic, and digest here. Can someone help explain what might be going on here? Beg pardon if this is discussed someplace else, I just couldn't find a post that addressed something of this nature.

Keep in mind that UW is (University of Washington) and NetID is a student's ID and they are using Shibboleth authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are able to build your own AuthType
which seems to be mod_pubcookie in your case
and is a Single-Sign-On for how i understand the 12 year old discussion about the same topic

[gossamer apache user posts](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/185487)

[htaccess UW Auth Type](http://www.washington.edu/webinfo/htaccess/weblogin.html)

Read 
[Apache Authentication Documents](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/auth.html)

for auth details.